# Rename file containing '-' character with sed

Tags: regex, awk, sed

A series of file names should be in format:

```
ABCDEF - XY1234 - FileName.ext
```

(The middle section is fixed length (2 alpha + 4 numeric), the first and last sections can be longer or shorter than the example. The extension will always be three alphanumeric characters.)

However, some files do not have the hyphens surrounded by spaces:

```
EFGHI- WX2345 -FileName.ext
JKLMN-VW3456 - FileName.ext
OPQRS - UV4567- FileName.ext
```

Is there a way to replace all these combinations "X -X", "X-X", and "X- X" with "X - X" using sed?

(I have tried the pattern of a non-whitespace character followed by a hyphen - `'\S\-'` as my pattern, but replacing this with a space followed by the hyphen `'\ \-'` then means I lose the character represented by the `'\S'`.  Had this worked my intention would have been to pass each filename through the three variations to ensure compliance.)

Comment: please update the question with your actual/complete code attempts for the replacements as well as the file renamings; are you using a `bash/mv` loop? are you using `rename`? something else?

Comment: could spaces show up anywhere else in the file name, other than before/after the hyphens? can hyphens show up anywhere else in the filename?

Comment: Hyphens will not be anywhere else in the file name, but spaces will be in the variable length sections.  My question doesn't relate to the mechanism for doing the renaming, it's about generating the destination pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to replace all these combinations "X -X", "X-X", and "X- X" with "X - X" using sed?

You may use this sed:

```bash
sed -E 's/[[:blank:]]*-[[:blank:]]*/ - /g' file

EFGHI - WX2345 - FileName.ext
JKLMN - VW3456 - FileName.ext
OPQRS - UV4567 - FileName.ext
```

**Breakdown:**

- `[[:blank:]]*-[[:blank:]]*`: matches `-` surrounded by 0 or whitespaces on both sides
- `-`: replaced that with `-` surrounded by a single space on both sides

An awk solution would be:

```bash
awk -F '[[:blank:]]*-[[:blank:]]*' -v OFS=' - ' '{$1=$1} 1' file

EFGHI - WX2345 - FileName.ext
JKLMN - VW3456 - FileName.ext
OPQRS - UV4567 - FileName.ext
```

or even this:

```bash
awk '{gsub(/[[:blank:]]*-[[:blank:]]*/, " - ")} 1' file
```

Comment: Thank you! That does what I wanted. I'll have a look at the awk examples. I may come back with questions if I can't wrap my head around something ;)

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions:

- white space only shows up before/after the hyphens
- there are only 2 hyphens in a filename
- all filenames contain 2 hyphens

One `bash` idea using parameter substitutions to determine new filenames:

```
while read -r fname
do
    newfname="${fname// /}"             # remove all spaces
    newfname="${newfname//-/ - }"       # add leading/trailing space to all hyphens
    # do something with (old) $fname and $newfname
done < <(printf "%s\n" 'EFGHI- WX2345 -FileName.ext' 'JKLMN-VW3456 - FileName.ext' 'OPQRS - UV4567- FileName.ext')
```

**NOTES:**

- `printf` only used here to simulate feeding list of filenames to the `while` loop
- OP would replace the `printf` with whatever command generates the list of filenames (eg, `find`, `cat list_of_filenames.txt`, etc)

Answer (score 0):

```
printf '%s' "${input_data}" | gtr '5MQ' "'" |
```

> ```
> mawk -F' ?[-] ?' '
>
> function  ___(_) {
>      return substr("", gsub("\47", "&\\\\&&",_))_ 
> }
> function ____(_) {
>      return sprintf("mv -vn \47%s\47\767\47%*s\47; ",
>                     ___($(_=_<_)),(NF = NF)*_,___($_)) 
>
> } ($!NF=____())^_' OFS=' - ' | LC_ALL=C column -s$'\767' -t
> ```

```
 1  mv -vn 'EFGHI- WX234'\'' -FileName.ext'      'EFGHI - WX234'\'' - FileName.ext'; 

 2  mv -vn 'JKL'\''N-VW34'\''6 - FileName.ext'   'JKL'\''N - VW34'\''6 - FileName.ext'; 

 3  mv -vn 'OP'\''RS - UV4'\''67- FileName.ext'  'OP'\''RS - UV4'\''67 - FileName.ext';
```

I took the liberty to modify some of the file names to showcase how this solution would properly escape single quotes within filenames. The output now can directly be piped into just about any shell to actually perform the renaming

if u never have any single quotes `'` or tabs `\t` in ur filenames, then it's a lot easier :

```
EFGHI- WX2345 -FileName.ext
JKLMN-VW3456 - FileName.ext
OPQRS - UV4567- FileName.ext
```

> ```
> gawk -be NF=NF FS='[- ]+' OFS=' - '
> ```

```
EFGHI - WX2345 - FileName.ext
JKLMN - VW3456 - FileName.ext
OPQRS - UV4567 - FileName.ext
```